# CSS borders dropshadow shows up when i reduce screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a header for a website. When I have the website on my normal, full browser width the header appears just as it's supposed to, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx9GH.png). However, as soon as I reduce the screen size to half the width, this pops up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/69g6G.png (the black bar that appears). I've tried using inspect element to trace where the dropshadow's coming from, but I have no idea where the problem is.

CSS code:

```
div#header {
        background:#41038e;
        min-width: 100%;
        height: 175px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px #666;
}
div#white-background {
        min-width: 100%;
        height: 125px;
        background:#FFF;
        padding: 0;
        z-index: -1;
}
div#header-inner {      
        width: 1200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        z-index: 1;
 }
 div#logo {
        height: 100px;
        padding-top: 25px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1200px;
  }
```

HTML:

```
       <div id="white-background">
                <div id = "logo"><!--begin logo-->
                    <h2>The Cupertino Florist</h2>
                    <!--<img src="img/logo.png" />-->
                </div><!--end logo-->
             </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

```
div#header {
    background:#41038e;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 175px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -2px #666;
}
```

Comment: @Andrew using `z-index` is no use here as it needs `positioning` of element first.